# Select most recent row from MySQL for set of distinct keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `foo` that looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ts       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| user     | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| a        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| b        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| c        | float        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

For each set of distinct (user, a, b), I'd like to select the most recent timestamp and the value c

I've tried a few variations of the following without any luck

```
select distinct user, b, c, ts as ts_b 
from (select max(ts) as ts_a from foo as max_ts) 
where ts_a = ts_b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select user,b,c, max(ts) as ts_b from foo
group by user,b,c
```

**UPDATE**

you can use this subquery to get what you need.  f2 will be the foo row that matches the distinct `user`,`a`,`b` and has the latest `ts`.  This is equivalent to the CROSS APPLY statement in MSSQL.

```
select f2.user,f2.a, f2.b,f2.c, f2.ts 
from  
(select distinct user,a, b from foo) f1 
inner join foo f2 
on f2.id = 
(select id
 from foo f3 
 where f3.user=f1.user and f3.a = f1.a and f3.b=f1.b
 order by f3.ts desc
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing back! That gets close, but I think it misses part of it -- I'm looking for the value of C at the most recent timestamp across distinct (user, b, c) tuples

Comment: @mythander889 I'm confused `c` is part of your tuple so there is only ever one value for `c`. Do you actually mean you want the value of `c` for the most recent timestamp across distinct `user`,`b`

Comment: Great catch -- sorry about that typo. I'm looking for the value of c for the most recent timestamp across distinct `user, a, b`

Comment: @mythander889 Try that

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery.  Here is one method:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where (user, b, c, ts) in (select user, b, c, max(ts) from foo group by user, b, c);
```

This gives you the entire row.  If you just want the maximum timestamp, that is the simple aggregation used as a subquery.

Comment: Can you do tuples in MySQL? Wow! Didn't know that one.

Comment: I gave it a shot and got the following error: ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.foo.user'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. I tried adding a group by (including user) on the end without any luck

Comment: @mythander889 . . . Yes, the `group by` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I like Bob Vale's answer of doing the max and the group by, but you mentioned you may want other values.

If you want other values associated with the row you can use a window function like row_number() to get the rows you are looking for, without it being in the group by.

```
select id, ts, user, a, b, c, row_rank
from (
select id, ts, user, a, b, c,
row_number() over (partition by user, b, c order by ts desc) as row_rank
from foo
) table_with_row_number
where table_with_row_number.row_rank = 1
```

Comment: That looks like it might do it! Thank you very much. I'm running into a syntax error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by user, b, c order by ts desc from HoldingsHistory) as r' at line 4`

Comment: Thought it was SQL Server. MySQL doesn't support row_number(), I think you are best doing another join similar to what Bob Vale suggested above in his latest edit.